# Typesetting the mathematical expression "const."

Tags: notation

How do I write in the right way, that something is constant?

I think, usually one does write `= const.`, which should be an abbreviation for the Latin `constat`.

Should I write the expression italic ($\textit{const.}$) or upright ($\textrm{const.}$)? As far as I know, fixed mathematical operators should be written upright, but this isn't an operator...

Comment: As I understand it, the rule is really that anything that is part of an actual word (rather than just the name of a variable) should be upright. Of course, the best thing to do is to search through some well-produced books and see if you can see how they do it.

Comment: Would this question not be better posed on tex.stackexchange?

Comment: @ZainPatel I wasn't sure. But it's also not an actual Tex/Latex question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Formally speaking, the right way to doing it would be to write something like
$$\int 2x\, \mathrm{d}x = x^2 + k, \ \text{where } k \text{ is constant}$$
If you did insist on doing it that way, to me it would look weird if it was italicised: italicised letters inside equations or formulae are usually interpreted as variables, so you *technically* end up with some ambiguity if any of the letters $c,o,n,s,t$ are used as variables. So I'd certainly prefer
$$\int 2x\, \mathrm{d}x = x^2 + \text{const.}$$
...but, of course, there is no Mathematical Institute of the Universe to govern this kind of thing, so as they say on Jersey Shore, you do you.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it written in both ways, and reckon it is more a matter of taste. 
Most frequently I have seen it in italics written as

$$
\cdots = const.
$$
This makes sense, I guess that fromo context it would be very difficult to confuse it with some other mathematical expression, such as the product of $c,o,n,s,t$.

Comment: The reason could of course just be that if you just type `const.` without any further commands in $\rm\LaTeX$ formulas, you get italics.

Comment: Good point you are making, that is likely.

Answer (score -2):

I believe your question has a definite answer if you fix a particular [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language), e.g. the [language of first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Syntax), in which you express a [well-formed formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula).

You could specify a constant symbol from the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)) of the language to address a particular term in the domain of discourse. You could use [quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) (if those exist in your language) to express a more complex association of an expression with a fixed member of the domain.

Comment: Oops, miss read the question.